# AHK WinWait Memory Usage

Tags: autohotkey

I have an ahk script I use to enable the `Printer` button on a Crystal Reports dialog that for what ever reason is not enabled by default when used in Server 2008 R2. Anyways... the issue I am having is the process when running continues to stack memory each cycle. Its not like I am storing any contents to a variable that happens to not get cleared. What in this process uses memory resources that don't get released and is there anything I can implement to prevent this from happening?

You can see in this listing that the private memory just grows as usage goes on. I ended up having it initiate about 5 times and it went from about 1000k to 2000k.

The top entry is my test version I converted from `WinWaitActive` that was causing unnecessary CPU usage.

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
 58       8     2312       6216    68     0.62   7828 showprinterbutton
 55       8     1788       5508    67    32.39   6840 ShowPSPrinter
 57       8     1864       6028    79    33.12   7184 ShowPSPrinter
 55       8     1396       5084    67     1.29   7604 ShowPSPrinter
 55       8     1796       5536    67    36.36   7856 ShowPSPrinter
 55       8     1772       5444    67    37.27   9848 ShowPSPrinter
 55       8     1740       5424    67    26.33  10300 ShowPSPrinter
 55       8     1396       4992    67     0.84  11348 ShowPSPrinter
 55       8     1396       5024    67     1.14  11460 ShowPSPrinter
 55       8     1736       5604    67   355.93  11676 ShowPSPrinter
 55       8     1396       4984    67     1.06  13364 ShowPSPrinter
 55       8     1396       5132    67     0.81  13516 ShowPSPrinter
 72       9     2048       6500    73    66.36  14072 ShowPSPrinter
 55       8     1792       5504    67    59.92  15736 ShowPSPrinter
 55       8     1400       4960    67     0.61  16340 ShowPSPrinter
 57       8     1496       5848    79     0.98  18516 ShowPSPrinter
 57       8     1500       5404    79     0.98  19048 ShowPSPrinter
 55       8     1400       5000    67     0.51  22020 ShowPSPrinter
```

Here is the script contents I have that is then compiled to run as an EXE.

```
; Version: 1.2
; Dated: 03/31/2015 - Created
; Description: Enable a watch for page setup dialog and activate the print button for crystal reports


; Only allow one instance to run
#SingleInstance force 

; Run with out a tray icon
#NoTrayIcon 

; Getting loose with not requiring direct title menu values
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

; Start active watch for quick post menu
WaitForPS:
WinWait,Page Setup
{
    Control,Show,,Button8,Page Setup,(optimize for screen display)
    GoSub WaitForPS
}


; End of Script...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after the moment the window appears and the loop ran one time, `WainWait` immediately continues to the next statement because the window already exists, enables the control, and recursively invokes the loop again (`gosub`), so the code allocated for example 100 stack frames per second thus eventually exhausting the call stack.

Instead use an [indefinite loop](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Loop.htm) and before continuing wait for the window to close:

```
Loop
{
    WinWait,Page Setup
    Control,Show,,Button8,Page Setup,(optimize for screen display)
    WinWaitClose
}
```

Comment: nailed it, thanks much! now I can deploy this to production and not stress over it.